# Atascado leyendo video de YouTube con C++ y wxWidgets

Tags: c++, socket

Estoy probando el sigiente código con un video de YouTube y se me queda en espera cuando llega a la funcion **Read**... parece que no recibe ningún dato y al cabo de un rato el socket se desconecta y la aplicación termina con normalidad.

```
int MainApp::OnRun()
{
    wxIPV4address addr;

    // address to connect
    wxString host = wxT("www.youtube.com");
    addr.Hostname(host);
    int port = 80;


    addr.Service(port);

    wxSocketClient *socket = new wxSocketClient();

    print(wxT("Connecting..."));

    socket->Connect(addr);

    if (socket->IsConnected())
        print(wxT("Connected to ") + addr.IPAddress());
    else
    {
        print(wxT("Can not connect to ") + host);
        return 1;
    } 

   **wxString request = wxT("GET /watch?v=NAsCGnXJ2cg HTTP/2.0\r\n");**


    // send the request to the server
    socket->Write(request.mb_str(), request.Length());
    print(wxT("Request sent"));


    char c = 0x00;
    wxString data;

    print(wxT("Receiving data..."));

    while( socket->IsConnected() && !socket->Error() )
    {
        // read a char
        socket->Read(&c, 1);

        // append char to string
        data.Append((wxChar)c, 1);

        cout<<c;
    }

    delete socket;

    // print received data
    print(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Creo que lo que está fallando es el **request** porque he probado el resto del código en mi servidor local y funciona correctamente (aunque tambien es verdad que no fue con un streaming).

¿Alguien sabe como hacer el **request** correctamente para que YouTube me envíe el los datos de vídeo?

> OK, siguiendo las intrucciones de la persona que me contestó hice la petición de esta forma.

wxString request = wxT("GET /watch?v=NAsCGnXJ2cg HTTP/2.0\r\n"

```
                      "Host: www.youtube.com\r\n"

                      "User-Agent: Chrome/63.0.3239.132\r\n"

                      "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"

                      "Content-Length: 0\r\n"

                      "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\r\n"

                      "\r\n"
                      );
```

Pero tengo el error 400 de mala petición...

> HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
>
> Content-Length: 1555
>
> Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2018 07:47:44 GM

**He estado mirando en la herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome y he visto esto**

> :authority: www.youtube.com
>
> :method: GET
>
> :path: /watch?v=rg9Dv1no_9c
>
> :scheme: https accept:
>
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>
> accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
>
> cache-control: max-age=0
>
> cookie: ...............
>
> upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
>
> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
>
> x-client-data: .............

Y en base a eso me he armado la siguinte petición

```
wxString request2 = wxT("GET /watch?v=rg9Dv1no_9c HTTP/2.0\r\n"
                        "Host: https://www.youtube.com\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n"
                        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n"
                        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n"
                        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 YaBrowser/18.2.0.284 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36\r\n"                            
                        "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n"
                        "Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9\r\n"
                        "Accept-Header: text/html, application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
                        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n" 
                         "Cookie: CONSENT=YES+ES.es+20150705-15-0; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=gW8EMr6HkB8; _ga=GA1.2.720111899.1436744695; endscreen-metadata-editor-gh=true; PREF=f6=42018&f5=30030&al=es&cvdm=grid&f1=50000000; SID=-gUT0RoqrW6iN-QgLD7uolElo-VW_2haDglvrB4reFtVFwk_pugPpzBzW1osmY5Gi_dS-g.; HSID=A7Yc2Drrdyl-yTKod; SSID=AMJGIbMZN1aWbu7EX; APISID=8eu4DiCJED9s0knC/A0bf8LsHROKIBE5UL; SAPISID=YLeTesbQP5mHdfD7/AuDiu6Z73WjgfW7Kv; LOGIN_INFO=AFmmF2swRAIgXfZGlAUHfvxB9mNWhpjTjVvH_k9DPNuS-mv9x6PZ4EMCIEuiOPCnkmUQ5JGgSl7TTNvrSJ2izUUDUOsnYB2VQZ_R:QUQ3MjNmemdfdUxtLTRRd3pCZ3lRNFQ3c1dDcjhsNEhuR2NzMjlPdEJkMVlUTTZycUM4Zm02ZERkV3AydW1PNDRJN0YyR0x4VHdLekw2ektFSi01M1ljM3ljNHJkaURVNkV6a3JncEJwTktubUlOOUdLRE5wdXlSM0VaVVJPV0p1aFNQOXRORWhiMWdYSVBCTmVIeTdNX3F4STBoUzlCNVVfd0lOZ0JUQk93M01IQmxhQktack80; YSC=JzQQe4Eiqfs\r\n"

                        "\r\n"

                        );
```

Pero sigo obteniendo el ERROR 400!!

**¿Alguna idea?¿Falta o sobra algo?¿Algún error en la sintáxis?**

Es raro porque he visto en algunas webs que se puede hacer con facilidad con un encabezado mucho mas simple... (estas dos por ejemplo)

https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/http-headers-tool

http://web-sniffer.net/

Obtienen el código HTML de la página del vídeo, lo cual me interesa para leer algunos datos interesantes.... pero mi objetivo final es poder capturar el streaming del video. Si me pueden orientar un poco con eso sería también estupendo!!

Comment: tambien he probado asi y me pasa exactamente lo mismo... en este caso me conecté a www.google.com
 wxString request = wxT("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBT2XRieQY4 \r\n");///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la cabecera que envias le falta información. El servidor se queda esperando un tiempo razonable a que llegue la información que falta y... como eso no sucede... corta la conexión.

La cabecera que envías debería parecerse más bien a esto:

```
GET /watch?v=NAsCGnXJ2cg HTTP/2.0
Host: www.youtube.com
User-Agent: (Como quieras identificar a tu cliente)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

Y cuidando muy mucho los saltos de línea... te recomiendo leerte la [especificación del protocolo HTTP](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/) para entender más sobre el tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias **eferion**, haré lo que dices y comentaré por aquí que tal me fue. Un Saludo!!

Comment: Lo intenté hacer con tu petición pero me sale error 400..

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2018 07:47:44 GM

No me cabe mas texto aquí... voy a ver si puedo editar  la pregunta y lo pongo ahí arriba

Comment: @IvánRodríguez ya es un progreso respecto a la situación inicial. estás intenando concetarte con youtube via http luego tienes que respetar el estándar para recibir lo que pretendes. El enlace al estándar te lo facilité en la respuesta. Si revisas con wireshark las cabeceras que envia un navegador verás que son muchas... quizás tengas que añadir las posibilidades de compresión o las de lenguaje esperado, opciones de cifrado, ... También puedes optar por usar una librería de terceros (como Qt) que disponga del protocolo ya embebido y tu solo tengas que usarlo

Comment: Lo de las Librerias de QT podrían ser una buena opción, antes las usaba pero me pasé a wxWidgets cuando Motorola compró el proyecto QT y también por las licencias.... pero tal vez sea menos trabajo de usar que leer todo el documento del protocolo HTTP que me has pasado (porque son un  montonazo de páginas) :-) ... la aplicación que quiero hacer es para uso personal, ni siquiera le quería poner interfaz gráfica... en fin, a seguir intentando... muchas gracías por tu ayuda.